# Read images from Thumbor

Tags: c#, thumbor

I am using `Thumbor` as `Docker` image on my PC. I am able to save the image to Thumbor but I am not able to read the image from URL

This is the method I am using to save the file

```
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(FileToByteArray(filename));            
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    try
    {
        httpContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
        response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:32773/image", httpContent).Result;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {

    }
```

And I am using this URL from the postman and it throws an error `400Bad Request`

```
http://localhost:32773/1.jpg
```

Am I missing something in the URL? Can anyone help me with a sample C# code? appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The correct request URL is:

```
http://localhost:32773/image/<the original location response>
```

Here is an example of storing an image

```
POST http://192.168.2.48:8082/image

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 11:56:12 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: /image/8ad1c65a3e6341cfb231b1faf438fc0e/image.jpg
Server: TornadoServer/4.5.3
```

Fetching the same image:

`GET http://192.168.2.48:8082/image/8ad1c65a3e6341cfb231b1faf438fc0e/image.jpg`

In short: make sure you store the Location information from the response header when storing an image